# Download all images from a website url

Tags: php, image

I need to download all images (only) from a url.
I've been searching but never got the right answer for this.
 I have a page that will accept website url to a input box then after submitting it will download all the images from that website.
I got this code from the web, but I dont know how to use or where to put the web url. For example i want to download all images from http://www.microsoft.com/en-ph/default.aspx

```
$url = $_REQUEST['webUrl'];
$string = FetchPage($url);

$image_regex_src_url = '/<img[^>]*'.
'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui';
$image_regex_src_url = '/<img[^>]*'.
'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui';
preg_match_all($image_regex_src_url, $string, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$images_url_array = $out[1];

foreach ($images_url_array as $pica)
{
    echo '<img src="'.$pica.'" >';
    $fileNames[] = $pica;
}
$_SESSION['filesArr'] = $fileNames;

function FetchPage($path)
{
    $file = fopen($path, "r"); 
    if (!$file)
    {
    exit("URL Unknown");
    } 

    $data = '';

    while (!feof($file))
    {
    $data .= fgets($file, 1024);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

This is my download script.

$files = array ('http://c.s-microsoft.com/en-ph/CMSImages/mslogo.png?version=856673f8-e6be-0476-6669-d5bf2300391d');
    $zip = new ZipArchive();

```
$tmp_file = tempnam('.','');
$zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

foreach($files as $file){

    $download_file = file_get_contents($file);
    $zip->addFromString(basename($file),$download_file);

}

# close zip
$zip->close();

# send the file to the browser as a download
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=download.zip');
header('Content-type: application/zip');
readfile($tmp_file);
```

Comment: The fact that you want to download some images does not necessarily mean that they're stored in a "image" folder...

Comment: How will i determine the images from the url?

Comment: Well, the quick idea is about this: instead of matching the url, first get the whole page using `file_get_contents` which will give you the raw code of the whole html page. Then, perhaps using `preg_match` with a valid pattern, match all the `<img>` tags and get all their `src` value which is, suddenly, the location of the image, either on their server or everywhere else :).

Comment: I did what you said, now my problem is i got links like http://c.s-microsoft.com/en-ph/CMSImages/mslogo.png?version=856673f8-e6be-0476-6669-d5bf2300391d but when i tried to download it using this link the file cant get the image

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `wget`... For example:

```
wget -r -A=.jpg,.png http://www.microsoft.com/en-ph/default.aspx
```

Comment: where would i add wget its my first time using it

Comment: Sorry, it's not php code... It's an external command, to be used on a terminal's shell prompt...

Comment: My answer excludes the use of PHP at all. You are supposed to use the command line. You can learn about it here: http://linuxtutorial.todolistme.net/commandline.php, for example...